# Too many Pinned Objects causing OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

We have an application written in .Net/C# 3.5 Compact Framework on an instrument.
We are using `Windows Compact Embedded 7` operating system.

This application in a large sense reads some data from the device and stores it in files on disk or SD Card and displays
the data in graphical/numerical fashion.

To read the data we are calling the driver by passing a byte array in the following manner.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll")]
         private static unsafe extern bool ReadFile(
                                               IntPtr hFile,
                                               byte* lpBuffer,
                                               uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
                                               uint* lpNumberOfBytesRead,
                                               uint lpOverlapped);



public int Read(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
         {
              uint temp;
              unsafe
              {
                   fixed (byte* pByte = &(buffer[index]))
                   {
                        if (!ReadFile(handle, pByte, (uint)count, &temp, 0)) 
                        {
                            return -1;
                        }
                   }
              }

              return (int)temp;
         }
```

And our read method which is running in a separate thread looks like this.

```
private void Reader()
{
  try
{
while(true)
{
byte[] data = new byte[1024*10];
Read(data,0,data.Length);
// Do something with data
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Our requirement is that the application is supposed to run for months continuously.

I have enabled the performance monitor on the instrumnet and when I run the app, stop it and see the statistics file generated by the perf monitor, i see we have millions of pinned objects which may eventually end up in memory leak.

Here is the stat file.

```
counter                                           total   last datum            n       mean        min        max
Total Program Run Time (ms)                    60240358            -            -          -          -          -
App Domains Created                                   1            -            -          -          -          -
App Domains Unloaded                                  2            -            -          -          -          -
Assemblies Loaded                                    16            -            -          -          -          -
Classes Loaded                                     2466            -            -          -          -          -
Methods Loaded                                     9685            -            -          -          -          -
Closed Types Loaded                                 598            -            -          -          -          -
Closed Types Loaded per Definition                  598            1           61          9          1         97
Open Types Loaded                                    16            -            -          -          -          -
Closed Methods Loaded                               184            -            -          -          -          -
Closed Methods Loaded per Definition                184            3           55          3          1         13
Open Methods Loaded                                   1            -            -          -          -          -
Threads in Thread Pool                                -            9           19          6          1          9
Pending Timers                                        -            0      1986882          0          0          4
Scheduled Timers                                 662294            -            -          -          -          -
Timers Delayed by Thread Pool Limit                   0            -            -          -          -          -
Work Items Queued                                662294            -            -          -          -          -
Uncontested Monitor.Enter Calls                30435505            -            -          -          -          -
Contested Monitor.Enter Calls                        72            -            -          -          -          -
Peak Bytes Allocated (native + managed)        10869964            -            -          -          -          -
Managed Objects Allocated                     386020616            -            -          -          -          -
Managed Bytes Allocated                     25202701076           16    386022691         65          8    1048588
Managed String Objects Allocated               39325752            -            -          -          -          -
Bytes of String Objects Allocated            3041772660            -            -          -          -          -
Garbage Collections (GC)                          24644            -            -          -          -          -
Bytes Collected By GC                       25218571932       936288        24644    1023314      49132    1528716
Managed Bytes In Use After GC                         -      6162292        24644    5988047     235620    6162292
Total Bytes In Use After GC                           -     10729796        24644   10045775    2113544   10729796
GC Compactions                                    24640            -            -          -          -          -
Code Pitchings                                        1            -            -          -          -          -
Calls to GC.Collect                                   0            -            -          -          -          -
GC Latency Time (ms)                             532689           23        24644         21          4        103
**Pinned Objects                                   846589**            -            -          -          -          -
Objects Moved by Compactor                     15728750            -            -          -          -          -
Objects Not Moved by Compactor                261474730            -            -          -          -          -
Objects Finalized                              14917931            -            -          -          -          -
Objects on Finalizer Queue                            -            0     14944139        303          0       2546
Boxed Value Types                              17838485            -            -          -          -          -
Process Heap                                          -         5968    101947181     156314        336     209656
Short Term Heap                                       -            0      4050880         51          0      79952
JIT Heap                                              -            0        27236     895917          0    1861844
App Domain Heap                                       -         1536        29669     960504       1536    1297080
GC Heap                                               -            0          208    4088477          0    7512064
Native Bytes Jitted                             3495028          136         8431        414         84     111248
Methods Jitted                                     8431            -            -          -          -          -
Bytes Pitched                                   1738556          164         4269        407         72     111248
Methods Pitched                                    4269            -            -          -          -          -
Method Pitch Latency Time (ms)                       78           78            1         78         78         78
Exceptions Thrown                                   171            -            -          -          -          -
Platform Invoke Calls                           9528151            -            -          -          -          -
COM Calls Using a vtable                              0            -            -          -          -          -
COM Calls Using IDispatch                             0            -            -          -          -          -
Complex Marshaling                              1929605            -            -          -          -          -
Runtime Callable Wrappers                             0            -            -          -          -          -
Socket Bytes Sent                                   784            -            -          -          -          -
Socket Bytes Received                              1934            -            -          -          -          -
Controls Created                                    255            -            -          -          -          -
Brushes Created                                 3022728            -            -          -          -          -
Pens Created                                    1888616            -            -          -          -          -
Bitmaps Created                                  166286            -            -          -          -          -
Regions Created                                      19            -            -          -          -          -
Fonts Created                                        31            -            -          -          -          -
Graphics Created (FromImage)                          0            -            -          -          -          -
Graphics Created (CreateGraphics)                    23            -            -          -          -          -
```

After reading on internet I found/understood that in the `Read` method we will have a pinned object but it should be unpinned again when we go out of the Read method.

We don't have any other code apart from the above code which is interacting to unmanaged environment.

I am looking for advices to fix this problem of pinned objects, is there any other way/tool which can help us in finding what are those pinned objects exactly are.

Is there any other better way to do this kind of managed/unmanaged communication ?

Comment: Fixed buffers are not actually pinned, you haven't found the real reason.  The finalizer queue looks dreadful with 1.5 million objects, I'd start with trying to diagnose why the finalizer thread stopped running.

Comment: @HansPassant: The "fixed" statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins" that variable during the execution of the statement. After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Posted code looks fine to me. Could it be you are not closing file handles properly ?

Comment: @HansPassant: How can we diagnose why the Finalizer thread stopped ? Is there any tool available, any suggestions ?

Comment: @HABJAN: We open file to store data in the beginning and keep it open until we stop read activity.

Comment: @ShrShr: Could you try to call GC.Collect from while to while?

Comment: @HansPassant I just want to point out that you never follow up any of your comments. Hopefully you read this one. Every time you drop a comment like that you've never returned to follow it up (from what I've seen). People would appreciate some more information from you..

Comment: @Simon - that's pretty nonsensical, I almost always follow up on comments to the answers I post.  And I have plenty of those, a lot more than most SO users, filled with information.  This question is unanswerable, all I can do is give the OP a hint.  If you prefer me to stop giving hints then I'm afraid I can't oblige you.  If the OP needs to know how to use a debugger to troubleshoot the finalizer thread then he should ask *that* question.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't mean your answers.. they are fantastic. You seem to drop random comments with no follow up. Of course its completely up to you whether you respond or not.. I just thought I would point out my observation with no malice intended.

Comment: OP did ask *that* question

Comment: The PendingTimers looks not right to me as well.  It may be related to your finalizer objects (which are probably the pinned objects you're having trouble with).  I'm with @HansPassant on this one - you're looking in the wrong place.  You need to find out what you've done in your finalizers that's preventing clean up, and I'd start by looking at classes using timers.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sir, how to use a debugger to troubleshoot the finalizer thread?

Comment: I don't know, Compact is different.  You really *do* have to click the Ask Question button.

Comment: @ctacke: Is there any other better approach of doing this kind of work, I mean newing a buffer and giving it to the driver, I heard about MemoryMappedFiles, do you have any suggestion/experience/recomendation on that ?

Comment: @ctacke: Do you know some tool or some way by which I can find out what is causing pinned objects ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the counter is referred to the number of object the system finds in the pinned state during a GC. If the read call can take a long time this may happen quite often. On the other side I think you can easily reduce the number of memory allocation performed by your app by simply moving the allocation of the data buffer outside the while loop. If it's size is fixed (as it seems from the code) or, at least, it's easy to determine a maximum size, re-allocating it at each iteration doesn't make sense. You mark the old one for gc and take new memory. You'll reach max memory threshold and gc will start. I don't know how long your app has been running, but allocating 386 million objecs looks like quite a big number. Avoid useless re-allocation (like the one in the code you posted) and using StringBuffers instead of strings, for example, can reduce the number of memory allocations, prevent the GC from running too often and, in general, improve your code efficence.

Comment: I have moved the initialization of the buffer out of while loop but I still get pinned objects, how can I figure out what is causing pinned objects ?

Comment: At least it should have reduced the number of GC runs...
To find the pinning issue you may try to comment out parts of your code (if you have multiple threads you may try to not spin some of them), trying to find the part that generates the issue. You may also try to use the CLR profiler of the GC heap viewer to try to understand better how your app manages memory. Having a GC doesn't mean that you can't have memory-related issues.

Comment: Even I have nothing just a call to the Read method, I still have many pinned objects.

Comment: Number of pinned objs matches the number of calls to Read, I suppose. Even after you moved the buffer alloationoutside of the loop, right?

Comment: Yes, not exact number of Read calls but approximately.